# Plot a histogram without zero values in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'd like to exclude all zero values from a histogram. Until now to do so I created a new object and transformed all zero values to NAs but I hoped there would be some easier way without creating new objects.

Example code:

```
set.seed(45)
a<-sample(0:10,500,replace=T)
c<-ifelse(a!=0,a,NA)
hist(c)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use subsetting like this:

```
hist( a[ !a==0 ])
```

You can check it works like so:

```
table(is.na(c))
FALSE  TRUE 
 443    57 

length(a[!a==0])
[1] 443
```

Comment: out of curiosity: why `!a==0` and not `a!=0`?

Comment: @plannapus for no reason at all really. Is there any difference *under the hood*? I am curious now.

Comment: @SimonO101 i don't think there is a true difference, it's just semantic: in one case you ask for the elements of `a` that are not in the group of the `a`s equal to 0 and in the other case you ask for the elements of `a` that are not equal to 0... which in the end are totally equivalent obviously, it's just that the second case seemed more logical to me.